# Variable forgotten when calling a function

Tags: python

This program I wrote ran into an infinity and crashed. The program contains a big for loop. I managed to locate which iteration of the for loop the problem occurred in. To help debug, I created a Boolean variable that would be true only for the bad iteration. Unfortunately, it isn't working as expected.

I've managed to come up with a simple example that reproduces the problem.

```
def troublemaker():
    print(trouble)

def program(iterations):
    for itnumber in range(iterations):
        print(itnumber)
        if itnumber==3:
            trouble=True
        else:
            trouble=False
        print(trouble)
        troublemaker()

program(5)
```

I expect the following output:

```
0
False
False
1
False
False
2
False
False
3
True
True
4
False
False
```

However I instead get:

```
...
3
True
False
...
```

Why?

Comment: No, your first version would produce a `NameError` when you run `program(5)` because at that point `trouble` is not defined for `troublemaker`, and it's not an existing global variable—unless you've previously defined it somewhere not shown. When you assign to `trouble` _inside_ `program`, you're only writing to a local variable that `troublemaker` cannot see.

Comment: When adding trouble as a global the code runs for me, but I cant reproduce your `3 True False` case.

Comment: Yeah, It should result in a NameError as @khelwood mentioned. I dont understand how troublemaker function is able to get value for trouble variable. Mystery :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to this line, `trouble=True` python thinks that `trouble` is a local variable and will not assign the value to `trouble` in the global scope. That's why you got that error.

**Global** keyword is a keyword that allows a user to modify a variable outside of the current scope. It is used to create global variables from a non-global scope i.e inside a function.

From Python Docs:

> All variable assignments in a function store the value in the local
>   symbol table; whereas variable references first look in the local
>   symbol table, then in the global symbol table, and then in the table
>   of built-in names. Thus, global variables cannot be directly assigned
>   a value within a function (unless named in a global statement),
>   although they may be referenced.

You can fix this using **global** keyword like that:

```
trouble = False

def troublemaker():
    print(trouble)

def program(iterations):

    global trouble

    for itnumber in range(iterations):
        print(itnumber)
        if itnumber==3:
            trouble=True
        else:
            trouble=False
        print(trouble)
        troublemaker()

program(5)
```